# SOAP could not connect to host with SSL Certificate in php

Tags: php, ssl, soap, certificate

I'm trying to send SOAP Request with **.PEM** Certificate.It throws an Exception

```
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host.
```

I'm sending SOAP Request like this

```
$params = array('trace' => 1,'exceptions' => 1, 
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
             'local_cert'=>'filename.pem'); // The SOAP File and Certificate file is in same Folder.So i didnt given any path. I tried with full path also.

   $url="filename.wsdl";
   $username="xxxx";
   $password="xxxxx";

        $client=new SoapClient($url,$params);

        $response=$client->createUser($credentials,$object);
```

Any one help me is the problem with SOAP Request Calling `.PEM` SSL authentication.Thanks

Comment: Try sending SOAP requests using SOAP UI first, bellow the wsdl request section fill in your authentication credentials.

Comment: i am not using SOAP UI and i am new for SOAP UI